# Plesk/Apache problems home directory

Tags: linux, centos

Currently we have a apache/plesk problem, it appears when we try to check all the configurations. This is the error log but the strange thing is that "sys_user_id 67" doesn't exist anymore. We deleted that subscription so it appears that it's stuck in some configuration file.

Here's our Plesk Configuration Log

```
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> Installed Plesk version/build: 11.0.9 CentOS 6 110120608.16

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> Detect system configuration
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] OS: CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Arch: x86_64

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> Validation of given db password
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Result: OK

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> Web server configuration checker version: 1.0.0

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> STEP 1: Checking for custom configuration templates...
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Result: OK

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> STEP 2: Checking for the JkWorkersFile directive in the Apache configuration...
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Result: OK

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> STEP 3: Checking associations between domains and IP addresses...
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Result: OK

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> STEP 4: Checking for corrupted reference between IP collections and IP addresses...
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Result: OK

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> STEP 5: Checking for links between APS applications and subscriptions...
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Result: OK

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> STEP 6: Checking for the Zend extension declaraion in php.ini...
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Result: OK

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> STEP 7: Check symbolic links for latest virtual host config files... 
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Result: OK

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> STEP 8: Checking for system users home directories consistency...
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] There is missing system user's login or home directory for sys_user_id 67 of hosting with www_root in /var/www/vhosts/wanmolen.nl/www/dev1 of domain 
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] There is missing Document Root directory /var/www/vhosts/wanmolen.nl/www/dev1 for domain on the filesystem for system user 
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] There is missing system user's login or home directory for sys_user_id 67 of hosting with www_root in /var/www/vhosts/wanmolen.nl/www/dev1/dev1 of domain 
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] There is missing Document Root directory /var/www/vhosts/wanmolen.nl/www/dev1/dev1 for domain on the filesystem for system user 
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] There is missing system user's login or home directory for sys_user_id 67 of hosting with www_root in /var/www/vhosts/wanmolen.nl/httpdocs/joomla of domain 
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] There is missing Document Root directory /var/www/vhosts/wanmolen.nl/httpdocs/joomla for domain on the filesystem for system user 
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] There is missing system user's login or home directory for sys_user_id 67 of hosting with www_root in /var/www/vhosts/wanmolen.nl/www/dev1/wanmolen of domain 
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] There is missing Document Root directory /var/www/vhosts/wanmolen.nl/www/dev1/wanmolen for domain on the filesystem for system user 
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] There is missing Document Root directory /var/www/vhosts/webrichard.nl/subdomains/joomla for domain on the filesystem for system user webrichard
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][WARNING] There are some inconsistencies in the Parallels Plesk Panel system users. Please check http://kb.parallels.com/113490 for solution and log file /root/webserver_configuration_issues.log for details.
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Result: Warning

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> STEP 9: Checking for multiple bootstappers in generated configurations dir...
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Result: OK

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> STEP 10: Checking for records with empty name field in the Configurations table...
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Result: OK

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> STEP 11: Checking for SElinux state...
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Result: OK

[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] ==> STEP 12: Checking for nginx ULIMIT value...
[2013-04-25 02:41:50][INFO] Result: OK
```

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

it's a database inconsistency between tables domains, hosting and sys_users. There is no automated solution, just check this tables by eyes and fix relations.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this url:
http://autoinstall.plesk.com/PSA_9.5.3/dist-pkg-FreeBSD-6.1-i386/ports_release/psa/pkg-install

Search for "sys_user_id" shows that installer script is looking for data in database. Maybe user 67 is left in some database table.